# How to set variable values to specific cell or element in BIRT

Tags: birt

I have declared variable in `beforeFactory` of BIRT Report.

**For example:**

[image: BIRT Global declaration]

This variable I am incrementing in table row render like:

[image: table render]

Now when all the rows are rendered I want to set above variable to specific cell/ element. I tried

> document.getElementName("numberOfMobilityFilesProcessed").text = numberOfMobilityFiles;

AND

> reportContext.getDesignHandle().getElementByID

but they are not working out for me.

Comment: Is the element numberOfMobilityFilesProcessed placed after the table, where the counter is being incremented? Depending on your answer it might be important to know, whether the report is being generated by a single RunAndRenderTask or by two separate tasks: RunTask and RenderTask.

Comment: @Vlad no that element is placed before table got rendered, that is the problem I was facing, if that element was placed after table I am able to set the value. I wanted to set value after table got rendered to that element.

Answer (score 1):

I had some problems with temporaly local variables used at multiple steps of datasource scripting so I always used global persisting.

After changing your variable you convert it to a String (because only Strings can be persisted) and before editing your variable again, you load the String from persisted context and convert it to the type you want (String to Integer are automatically converted by JavaScripts dynamic typed variables, but don't forget the `toString()` when you are saving otherwise you will risk an error).

Because you are using `reportContext.setPersistentGlobalVariable` your variable is accessable in every Element of your Report.

Example:

```
var rowNum = reportContext.getPersistentGlobalVariable("row_number");
if(rowNum == null){
  rowNum = -1;
}
rowNum++;
reportContext.setPersistentGlobalVariable("row_number", rowNum.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you have a text element displaying a number of row in a table element. The text element appears before the table in the report.

If you are using two separate tasks RunTask and RenderTask:

Add a report variable in your report (see "variable" node on the Data Explorer view). Then you can change the report variable in onCreate() event handler of the table row:

```
vars["numberOfSomething"] = vars["numberOfSomething"] + 1;
```

and access its value in an onRender() evenet handler of some text element, for instance DynamicText:

```
this.text = "Number of something: " + vars["numberOfSomething"];
```

If you are using RunAndRenderTask, you must look for another approach. In this case an order of onCreate() and onRender() calls is different. You could bind the same DataSet to the text element displaying the counter, as the one bound to the table. Than you can add an aggregation binding to the text element that will count all rows in the dataset.